# How to redirect react app to non www with htaccess file?

Tags: reactjs, apache, .htaccess

I have one of react app working with apache server.
Here is my .htaccess file

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

and i want to redirect [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) requests to domain.com,
anyway how can i redirect requests www to non-www with htaccess ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
#www to non-www redirection
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1/$1 [NE,L,R=301]
#rewrite non-files to index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```